# Adding a button to 2 LinearLayout?

Tags: android

I made a design for my app but as far as I can imagine
I have to a button into two different LinearLayouts.

Is it possible under Android?

Edit:

Code

```
        _configureButton = new Button(context);
        _callButton = new Button(context);
        _messageButton = new Button(context);

        _contactImage = new ImageView(context);

        LinearLayout _verticalMainview = new LinearLayout(context);
        LinearLayout _callAndMessageView = new LinearLayout(context);

        LinearLayout _horizontelMainview = new LinearLayout(context);

        LinearLayout _settingsAndMessageView = new LinearLayout(context);

//...


        _callAndMessageView.addView(_callButton);
        _callAndMessageView.addView(_messageButton);

        _verticalMainview.addView(_configureButton);
        _verticalMainview.addView(_contactImage);
        _verticalMainview.addView(_callAndMessageView);

        _horizontelMainview.addView(_contactImage);
        _horizontelMainview.addView(_settingsAndMessageView);

        _settingsAndMessageView.addView(_configureButton);
        _settingsAndMessageView.addView(_messageButton);
```

Now code crashes. Or I should use GridLayout?

Comment: Your can have many linearlayouts and buttons in a view. Please explain your problem implementing this in more detail

Comment: I have to add a button to a vertical LinearLayout and a horizontal LinearLayout to control the button. (Actually several buttons who have a different location so they stay in the same size)

Comment: Okay, yes, it is possible. Please show the XML that you currently are working with

Comment: I add the code I code. It isnt an XML code.

Comment: Why is it not XML? Doing so and using `LayoutInflater` would be much simpler. Anyways, LinearLayout defaults to vertical orientation.

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm pretty sure `LinearLayout` defaults to horizontal.

Comment: @MikeM. It's been a while since reading that doc. Thanks.

Comment: @snowparrot "*Now code crashes*" -- If you are going to edit the question and say that the code crashes, then add the logcat, please

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible that a view has two parents.